# BASH args with DIR1 DIR2 DIR3

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

i am trying to check if an Folder(Directory) exists that we get from the args. 
example:

```
./file.sh Dir1 Dir2 Dir3 etc..
```

so i have to check if the Directory(Dir1 $1) exists and then do something and THEN i should jump for the next args(Directory that we get,$2) and do the same thing ...etc..

i know to do that :

Examining Folder Exists

```
if [ -d $* ];
then
echo "The specified folders exists"
for item in $LOCATION/*
do
.....
done


else

echo "The specified folders does NOT exists, Iam EXITING"

exit 0

fi
```

But like that i am checking all the Folders at once and if one of them not there he gonna exit. So i want him to check 1 after the other and when he get one that don't exit he should stop.

Comment: Please show what you already tried.

Comment: this code up there iam trying to repair it .. but i dont have a clue how to check args ... iam doing a much of things example iam searching for size and type etc but this thigs gonna come in do .. but the problem is the start how can i let him check args by args (one after the other)

Comment: There is several parts missing… such as iterating over the arguments (use `"$@"` not `$*` there). Also, test -d does not take a vector (which `$*` is) but a single argument (which you also will need to quote).

Comment: its working like that if u delete the for loop its working u can try it u can give the Directories as args and he gonna check if they exist or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for DIR in "$@" ; do
  if [ ! -d "$DIR" ] ; then
    echo "$DIR does not exist.  I am EXITING"
    exit 1
  fi
  echo "$DIR exists, continuing on."
  ... add whatever code you want to do on $DIR here ...
done
```

Comment: but when he find Dir that exist, he should Stop and make a couple of commands, like that he gonna just echo? another question why exit 1 ? and not exit 0 ?

Comment: Well, obviously, you can do whatever you want in place of the 'echo', that was just for simplicity sake.

We use 'exit 1' instead of 'exit 0' as a matter of convention.  Exit 0 means the command successfully completed, in this case, it hasn't.

Comment: The question also seems to be quite underspecified…

Comment: To expand upon the 'exit #' business.  Any number you provide after the exit is what gets set as the "exit status" in the shell.  Typically, an exit status of 0 means everything worked the way it was supposed to. Anything else, means it didn't work the way it was expected.  You can use any number between 0 and 255 for the exit status.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop through each directory individually with `$@`, rather than checking them all at once with `$*`:

```
for dir in "$@"; do
  if [[ -d "$dir" ]]; then
    # and so on
```

Comment: 1 more thing befor i try it the names of the Dir's are not the same he can wrote anything . So how i do that ? or its gonna work like that ?